# Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'texture'. But it does

Tags: swift, sknode

I created this SpriteKitNode:

```
let examp = examps[examps.count-1] // examps is a global array with SKNodes inside of it
```

But when I try to change its texture I receive this error:

```
examp.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "examp2")
```

> Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'texture'

However, it has a value of 'texture' so I don't know what the solution is.

https://imgur.com/a/s1V0XZF

Comment: Are you sure that `examp` is declared as local constant?

Comment: no, it's not. it's taken from a global array with SKNodes. is that fine?

I edited my code to what it actually is now, sry for that

Comment: Please try to understand the error. The base class `SKNode` doesn't have a member `texture`, only the subclass `SKSpriteNode` has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`examps` is `[SKNode]`. This means that `examp` is `SKNode`, not `SKSpriteNode` even if `examps[examps.count-1]` happens to hold an `SKSpriteNode`.

In order to access the `texture` property, you need to cast the result of `examps[examps.count-1]` to an `SKSpriteNode`.

```
if let examp = examps[examps.count-1] as? SKSpriteNode {
    examp.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "examp2")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I thought I could simply access the 'texture' property since it was included in my examp constant